# How to optimize nested for loop or alternative approach for the below scenario

Tags: python, list, tuples, nested-loops

I have list of tuple which is of length `[(4, 7, 10), (12, 40, 47), (2, 12, 23), (13, 16, 17), (37, 38, 47).... (41, 47, 48)` more than 2000 and the length of tuple is 3. My objective is to find all set of 3 tuple

which follow these Rule:

1. The first element of the 1st tuple should be less than the 2nd element of the second tuple and the third element of the 3rd tuple should be less than the 2nd element of the second tuple.
   `t[0][0] < t1[1][1] < t3[2][2]` 
   example: Tuples 1,3 & 4.`(**4**, 7, 10), (2, **12**, 23), (13, 16, **17**)`

`**4 < 12 < 17**`

2. There should not be any duplicate values in the set. For example: 1,2 & 4th tuple in a list can be considered `(4, 7, 10) (12, 40, 47) & (13, 16, 17)`. We didn't consider the 3rd since it has an element 12, which already there in the second tuple `(12, 40, 47)`.
3. If we pick a 1st tuple from index 1 we should check the second tuple from index greater than 1 and the 3rd tuple's index should be greater than the 2nd tuple's index.

Below is my program, the problem is time taken for finding the all sets if the range is 500+ is very high more than 30 minutes to unknown. Please help me to optimize it.

```
    ts = datetime.now()  

    outcomes = loadSample("sample_data.txt")

    ne = outcomes[0:300]



    combinationsList = []

    for i in range(0,len(ne)):             
        for j in range(i+1,len(ne)):
            tt1 = []
            tt1.append(ne[i])            
            tt1.append(ne[j])
            if not (ne[i][0] < ne[j][1]) and (len(set((itertools.chain(*tt1)))) == 6): continue
            for k in range(j+1,len(ne)): 
                t1 = []                           
                                                        
                t = (i, j, k)
                
                t1.append(ne[i])
                t1.append(ne[j])
                t1.append(ne[k])
                
                
                if (ne[j][0] < ne[k][1]) and (len(set((itertools.chain(*t1)))) == 9): 

                    A=np.array([ne[i],ne[j],ne[k]])
                    
                    b = np.diag(A)
                    
                    is_sorted = lambda a: np.all(a[:-1] <= a[1:])
                    if is_sorted(b):
                        combinationsList.append(t)                        
                        
    print("Time to create : ",datetime.now() - ts)
```

You can find the Tuples file here, which i use for testing.

[sample_data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pFHL2dBuMBkzmDOtjQaP-4G-F7nwTj-g/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are checking "the compatibility" (i.e. whether the diagonal elements are ascending and whether there are duplicate elements) of the tuples very many times. It should be faster to check pairs of tuples first and store their compatibility. Afterwards you then can combine two pairs of compatible tuples of which one tuple is identical.

Comment: Sounds like a valid suggestion. One more note, this length of the tuple can vary upto to 8. ill modify the code as per you suggestion and post the result here.

Comment: Pandas is good to use with less codes if you are no restriction to use.

Comment: I dont have any restriction, can you share some example of how to achieve it.

Comment: Out of curiosity - may I ask what's the use-case for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option1 - dictionary based

I believe this is an optimized solution. The general idea is to build two dictionaries of potential matches:

- from the second tuple to the first tuple (match_21).
- from the second tuple to the third tuple (match_23).

In addition, we're building a set of potential matches between tuple-1 and tuple-3 (match_13).

We're then iterating over all the potential second tuples, and look for matches between items in the potential tuple1 list and the potential tuple3 list by checking if they exist in match_13.

```
import itertools
import datetime

ts = datetime.datetime.now()  

print("Reading file")
tuples = []
with open("Sample_data.txt") as f:
    for line in f: 
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
        t = tuple(int(x) for x in line.split(","))
        tuples.append(t)

print(f"loaded {len(tuples)} tuples")

print("Building match 1-2")
match_21 = {}
for t2 in range(1, len(tuples)-1):
    matches_for_t2 = []
    for t1 in range(t2):
        if tuples[t1][0] < tuples[t2][1] and set(tuples[t1]).isdisjoint(tuples[t2]):
            matches_for_t2.append(t1)
    match_21[t2] = matches_for_t2
print(len(match_21))

print("Building match 2-3")
match_23 = {}
for i in range(1, len(tuples)-1):
    matches_for_i = []
    for j in range(i+1, len(tuples)):
        if tuples[i][1] < tuples[j][2] and set(tuples[i]).isdisjoint(tuples[j]):
            matches_for_i.append(j)
    match_23[i] = matches_for_i

print(len(match_23))


print("Building match 1-3")
match_13 = set()
for t1 in range(0, len(tuples)-2):
    for t3 in range(t1 + 1, len(tuples)):
        if tuples[t1][0] < tuples[t3][2] and set(tuples[t1]).isdisjoint(tuples[t3]):
            match_13.add((t1, t3))
print(len(match_13))

print("Looking for matches")
counter = 0 
max_t2 = len(tuples)-1
# max_t2 = 20 # for debugging

matches = []
for t2 in range(1, max_t2):
    potential_t1 = match_21[t2]
    potential_t3 = match_23[t2]
    for t1, t3 in itertools.product(potential_t1, potential_t3):
        if (t1, t3) in match_13:
            match = (t1, t2, t3)
            matches.append(match)    

    print(".", end="")

print(len(matches))
print(matches[:10])

print("Time to create : ", datetime.datetime.now() - ts)
```

This takes about 2:15 minutes on my laptop.

### Option2 - using pandas

The other alternative is to leverage the power of pandas to merge multiple datasets. It's faster, but not dramatically faster.

```
print("Reading file")
tuples = []
with open("Sample_data.txt") as f:
    for line in f: 
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
        t = tuple(int(x) for x in line.split(","))
        tuples.append(t)
tuple_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tuples)
tuple_df.reset_index(inplace = True)

t = pd.merge(tuple_df.assign(dummy = 1), tuple_df.assign(dummy = 1), 
             on = "dummy", suffixes=["_t1", "_t2"])

# create 1-2 match 
m_12 = t[(t.index_t1 < t.index_t2) & (t["0_t1"] < t["1_t2"])]

cond = (m_12["0_t1"] != m_12["0_t2"]) & (m_12["1_t1"] != m_12["0_t2"]) & (m_12["2_t1"] != m_12["0_t2"]) & \
(m_12["0_t1"] != m_12["1_t2"]) & (m_12["1_t1"] != m_12["1_t2"]) & (m_12["2_t1"] != m_12["1_t2"]) & \
(m_12["0_t1"] != m_12["2_t2"]) & (m_12["1_t1"] != m_12["2_t2"]) & (m_12["2_t1"] != m_12["2_t2"])

m_12 = m_12[cond]

# create 2-3 match 

t = pd.merge(tuple_df.assign(dummy = 1), tuple_df.assign(dummy = 1), 
             on = "dummy", suffixes=["_t2", "_t3"])

m_23 = t[(t.index_t2 < t.index_t3) & (t["1_t2"] < t["2_t3"])]

cond = (m_23["0_t2"] != m_23["0_t3"]) & (m_23["1_t2"] != m_23["0_t3"]) & (m_23["2_t2"] != m_23["0_t3"]) & \
(m_23["0_t2"] != m_23["1_t3"]) & (m_23["1_t2"] != m_23["1_t3"]) & (m_23["2_t2"] != m_23["1_t3"]) & \
(m_23["0_t2"] != m_23["2_t3"]) & (m_23["1_t2"] != m_23["2_t3"]) & (m_23["2_t2"] != m_23["2_t3"])

m_23 = m_23[cond]

# create 1-3 match

             on = "dummy", suffixes=["_t1", "_t3"])

m_13 = t[(t.index_t1 < t.index_t3) & (t["0_t1"] < t["2_t3"])]

cond = (m_13["0_t1"] != m_13["0_t3"]) & (m_13["1_t1"] != m_13["0_t3"]) & (m_13["2_t1"] != m_13["0_t3"]) & \
(m_13["0_t1"] != m_13["1_t3"]) & (m_13["1_t1"] != m_13["1_t3"]) & (m_13["2_t1"] != m_13["1_t3"]) & \
(m_13["0_t1"] != m_13["2_t3"]) & (m_13["1_t1"] != m_13["2_t3"]) & (m_13["2_t1"] != m_13["2_t3"])

m_13 = m_13[cond]

# Merge 1-2 and 2-3
m_123 = pd.merge(m_12[["index_t1", "index_t2"]], m_23[["index_t2", "index_t3"]], on="index_t2")

# filter by valid 1-3 matches 
res = pd.merge(m_123, m_13[["index_t1", "index_t3"]], on = ["index_t1", "index_t3"], how = "inner")
```

All in all, this takes about 1:15 minutes on my laptop (but requires a lot of memory).

Comment: The solution looks good, can you explain how to extend it to tuple of length 4

Comment: Do you mean to sets 4 tuples, each with length 4?

Comment: yes, instead of tuple length 3, tuple length is 4 example: (4, 7, 10, 20)

Comment: What I would probably do is build pair from 1-2, 2-3, and 3-4. then find all the 1-2-3 combinations like above, and then look for matches between 1-2-3 and 3-4.

Comment: In any case, if this answer your original question, it would be great if you could accept it as answer - for future generations, and I would also appreciate it.

Comment: it improves the performance till when the range is 1300, after that system performance is slow and more than 20 minutes system is not usable, so had to stop the process.

Comment: Looking for more optimized solution.

Comment: Will you consider using pandas, which can do some of that in a vectorized manner?

Comment: And another question - will you consider using parallelism? Do you consider that an optimization?

Comment: One last note - with your sample data of ~1830 tuples, my code ran for 4:30 minutes on my laptop. **Much** less than the 30 minutes you mention in the question.

Comment: Will you consider using pandas, which can do some of that in a vectorized manner? And another question - will you consider using parallelism? Do you consider that an optimization? –  Whatever helps me to improves the performance. Can you share some examples of how to use it.

Comment: What about the fact that for the entire data, it ran for 4.5 minutes on my laptop? How much time did it take you?

Comment: Time to create :  0:40:46.684066, this is better than my implementation, but expecting something to run in few minutes.

Comment: Did another optimization. Runs in about 2:15 minutes on my laptop. Can you give it a try?

Comment: By the way - what kind of hardware are you running on?

Comment: I am using i5 5th gen & 8 GB ram. Now it takes only 0:02:38.844798. it is great.

Comment: Can you describe how to extend this to tuple of length 4, since it is tuple of length 3, how to change this to achieve the expected result.                                                                  for t2 in range(1, max_t2):
    potential_t1 = match_21[t2]
    potential_t3 = match_23[t2]
    for t1, t3 in itertools.product(potential_t1, potential_t3):
        if (t1, t3) in match_13:
            match = (t1, t2, t3)
            matches.append(match)

Comment: 4 tuples - are you referring to the dict solution or the pandas one?

Comment: Dict solution looks good for me, since pandas i got this error MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.78 GiB for an array with shape (239133025,) and data type int64

Comment: For 4-tuples, I would do the following: (1) find matches for tuples 2-3. (2) Build potential dicts for (2.3) -> 1 and (2,3) -> 4; (3) build a set of possible 1-4 matches. (4) Do the final loop to compliment the 2-3 pairs to 3-4. Keep in mind that it would take **a lot** of time with large data.